# How to Show Date into words in odoo 12 reports

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I am using odoo 12 and want to show Date field record from a model into Reports, how can i do this?
Still facing error
`time data 'False' does not match format '%d %B, %Y'`

here is my code

```
@api.multi
def _get_student_dob_in_words(self, student_id):
    
    date_of_birth = fields.Date('BirthDate', default=fields.date.today(),
                            states={'done': [('readonly', True)]})
    
    student = self.env['student.student'].search([('id','=',student_id)])
    date_of_birth = student.date_of_birth
    # date_of_birth = date.today()
    # %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
    strp_date = datetime.strptime(str(date_of_birth),"%d %B, %Y")
    # dob_result = datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT).date()
    # str_dob_result = str(date_of_birth)
    strp_dob_result = num2words(strp_date)
    strp_dob_result = strp_dob_result.upper()
   
    return [{
            'dob_in_words': strp_dob_result}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `strptime` at all, you may use `strftime`. You still have to test if date is present. And i would make it as computed field as well.

```py
_{name|inherit} = 'student.student'

#date_of_birth = fields.Date(...
date_of_birth_words = fields.Char(compute='_compute_dob_in_words', store=True)

@api.depends('date_of_birth')
def _compute_dob_in_words(self):
    for student in self:
        if student.date_of_birth:
            date_of_birth = student.date_of_birth
            
            month = date_of_birth.strftime('%B') #date_of_birth.month
            day = num2words.num2words(date_of_birth.day, to='ordinal')
            year = num2words.num2words(date_of_birth.year)
            student.date_of_birth_words = "{} {} in year {}".format(day, month, year).upper()
```